# seetter connot be specified for readonly property upgrade to swift2.0

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7

Meet a warning when I upgrade the project code to swift 2.0.

```
public class Extension : NSObject {
  private(set) public var name : String = ""
}
```

Above code will prompt warning：setter connot be specified for a readonly property.
Currently, how to update these code to adapt swift2.0

Comment: That code compiles without errors/warnings in my Xcode 7.0.1 with Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

["The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1): Access Control"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) writes:

> You can make property getter public, and its property setter private, by combining the public and private(set) access level modifiers:

Therefore, it's legal:

```
public class Extension : NSObject {
    public private(set) var name : String = ""
}
```

PS: By the way, it works for Swift 2.0 too.

Comment: I had try the legal, but the warning is still prompt.

Comment: @Rafu actually have no idea why that happens.